# Component View displaying with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have having issues following the tutorial of component development of Joomla. The tutorials I followed related to the issue are [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_backend_actions) and [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/2.5/Adding_decorations_to_the_backend).

I can view the default view properly, but when I click the `new` or `edit` and `delete` button, or when I browse too `../administrator/index.php?option=com_testimonials&view=testimonial&layout=edit` I get that error.

I have rechecked the code so many times but I just can't find where I went wrong.

File: controllers\testimonial.php

```
class TestimonialsControllerTestimonial extends JControllerForm
{
    //Nothing yet as per the tutorial
}
```

File: models\testimonial.php

```
class TestimonialsModelTestimonial extends JModelAdmin {
    public function getTable($type = 'Testimonials', $prefix = 'TestimonialsTable', $config = array()) {
        return JTable::getInstance($type, $prefix, $config);
    }

    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true) {
        // Get the form
        $form = $this -> loadForm('com_testimonials.testimonial', 'testimonial', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));
        if(empty($form)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $form;
    }

    protected function loadFormData() {
        // Check the session for previously entered form data
        $data = JFactory::getApplication() -> getUserState('com_testimonials.edit.testimonial.data', array());
        if(empty($data)) {
            $data = $this -> getItem();
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

File: views\testimonial\view.html.php

```
class TestimonialsViewTestimonial extends JView {

    protected $form = null;

    public function display($tpl = null) { 
        //get the data
        $form = $this -> get('Form');
        $item = $this -> get('Item');

        $this -> form  = $form;
        $this -> item = $item;
        $this -> addToolbar();

        parent::display($tpl);
        $this -> setDocument();


    }

    protected function addToolBar() {
        JRequest::setVar('hidemainmenu', true);
        $isNew = ($this -> item -> id == 0);
        JToolBarHelper::title($isNew ? JText::_('COM_TESTIMONIALS_MANAGER_TESTIMONIAL_NEW') : JText::_('COM_TESTIMONIALS_MANAGER_TESTIMONIAL_EDIT'), 'testimonials');
        JToolBarHelper::save('testimonial.save');
        JToolBarHelper::cancel('testimonial.cancel', $isNew ? 'JTOOLBAR_CANCEL' : 'JTOOLBAR_CLOSE');

    }

    protected function setDocument() {
        $isNew = ($this -> item -> id < 1);
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();        
        $document -> setTitle($isNew ? JText::_('COM_TESTIMONIALS_TESTIMONIAL_CREATING') : JText::_('COM_TESTIMONIALS_TESTIMONIAL_EDITING'));
    }
}
```

File:  `views\testimonial\tmpl\edit.php`

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_testimonials&layout=edit&id='.(int) $this -> item -> id); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="testimonial-form">
    <fieldset class="adminForm">
        <legend><?php echo JText::_('COM_TESTIMONIALS_TESTIMONIAL_DETAILS'); ?></legend>
        <ul class="adminFormList">
            <?php foreach($this -> form -> getFieldset() as $field): ?>
                <li><?php echo $field -> label; echo $field -> input; ?></li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="testimonial.edit" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: One reason when it only shows component is your url may have tmpl=component.

Comment: @Irfan, It was a naming problem I fixed that I have changed my question to the real issue. I am sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your view folder name. Change `testimonials folder name to testimonial` as you have specified view=testimonial.

let me know if it does not work.

Update:
As discussed your table having naming problem-

```
class TestimonialsTableTestimonial extends JTable 
{ 
public function __construct(&$db) { 
parent::__construct('#__testimonial_table', 'id', $db); 
} 

function bind($array, $ignore = '') 
{ 

return parent::bind($array, $ignore); 
} 

}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was typo too. Actually I have another view `testimonials` too, that is setup as default view.

Comment: @mrN:What error are you getting now? check your controllers/testimonial.php

Comment: 500 Internal Server error when I browse too ../administrator/index.php?option=com_testimonials&view=testimonial&layout=edit

Comment: @mrN:It would be great if you can post your controller and model code with path.

Comment: @mrN:Once thing which looks problematic is getTable($type = 'Testimonials' Change it to- getTable($type = 'Testimonial' and check tables/testimonial.php

Comment: I don't have the Table for this controller sepa\rately. I want to use the same for `Testimonials` controller. What do you suggest?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18163/discussion-between-irfan-and-mrn)