# Joomla Component data from model to view

Tags: model-view-controller, view, joomla, model, components

I am creating a component in Joomla for the first time, now i am having a hard time calling data from  my model in to my view. I did this as follows:

//In my model

```
    class InternetModelDefault extends JModel {

      public function test(){
        $this->test='test';
      }

    }
```

//In my view

```
class InternetViewInternet extends JView {
        $model = $this->getModel();
        $test = $model->test();
        var_dump($test);

      // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);
    }

}
```

The output gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object in
>   /var/websites/www.infrait.nl/content/components/com_internet/views/internet/view.html.php
>   on line 66

Where does it went wrong? Please some help..

***Current mapstructure:***
http://imgdump.nl/hosted/ad9e57de83060b3240f8fc6bba99237b.png 
As i am new i can only share you this direct link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your model.php like this

```
jimport ('joomla.application.component.modellist');
class InternetModelInternet extends JModelList
{
  public function test(){
        $this->test='test';
      }

    }
```

and in view.html.php get model

```
    jimport ('joomla.application.component.view');
    class InternetViewInternet extends JView
    {
    public function display ($tpl = null)
        {

            $model = &$this->getModel ();
             $test = $model->test();
                    var_dump($test);
                 // Display the view
                parent::display($tpl);
        }
}
```

Comment: still won't work either. Added the & en de modellist.import. Same error also.

Comment: means you can't get model here try this link for fetch model manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159536/how-to-use-multiple-models-in-joomla-mvc-component let me know if you have still any issue

Comment: Did the job, youre great. THX!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because object is not initiated properly.Change class name to `InternetModelInternet`. And model file name will be `internet.php`.

Let me know if it does not work.

Comment: I changed my model class name from InternetModelDefault to InternetModelInternet, also created a new model class page and keeped my default. Not sure if that's right ?

Comment: Could you please give more info about path,class and file?

Comment: i will add a PS of my mapstructure in the qeustion, the class it self only need to output "test".

The component himself is a postalchecker for customers to show which packages we got in their region, handled by a JSON API. 

PrintScreen available in a min.

Comment: hope this helps, img uploaded

Comment: to push info from a controller to view i use assignref. Does a model also need a assign?

Comment: @JSkirMan:Are you still getting error if not return the result from test function.

Comment: instead of test() i used $this->test; and added a assignref in my model. This returns a NULL to my page, at least not an error, haha. But still not where i needed to be

Comment: You can read this post-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929169/component-view-displaying-with-500-interval-server-error/12929925#12929925